# Cordova 4.x/phonegap webintent

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I tried on a variety of plugins webintent, but i can't do that.

I must send image from e.g. gallery, to cordova app.

My code

```
    window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(WebIntent.EXTRA_STREAM,
        function(url) {
            // url is the value of EXTRA_TEXT
            console.log(url);
        }, function() {
            console.log('?');
            // There was no extra supplied.
        }
    );
```

I testing on chrome. And according to the plugin webintent, there are two options.
function with url send null, or error function send ?

Probably problem is the plugins to max version cordova 3.x

How do I get to send the photos from gallery to phonegap/cordova 4.x app?

Comment: Perharps solve your problem... https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent/issues/23

Comment: I found this earlier, but did not work.

Comment: Im having the same problem: according to adb, the error I see is "Invalid action" (which Im assuming are the getExtra() calls failing).

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/florentvaldelievre/virtualartifacts-webintent instead?

Comment: @Eno, I solved the problem some time ago
https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent/issues/39